# In Magento what is the appropriate time for local overrides vs setting up a module?

Tags: php, magento

This question is related to best practice:

As an example is it safe and in good form to copy

`app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php`

or other similar files to

`app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php`

if I need to modify a function? if not, what else should be done?

I feel like most of what I've read says this is just fine but there has been a lot of talk about custom modules as well. Would it be better to modify/override the file via a custom module (`app/code/local/company/custom/...`)? What is the appropriate time for local overrides vs setting up a module?

Finding the solution to a problem online tends to be easy, doing so in best practice is much more difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways of modifying core behavior, in order from good to (really) bad:

- Use an observer on a core event.
- Use a class rewrite.
- Copy the file to `app/code/local/Mage`.
- Modify it in the `app/code/core/Mage` directly.

Unfortunately, you can't do class rewrites on Abstract classes, so in this case you will have to use the 3rd option.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What about the first option?

Comment: @Front_End_Dev: That entirely depends on what you're trying to change/modify :-)